# Нужна помощь со вложенными списками (python)

Tags: python, list

Существует список студентов  и их любимый предмет, и есть сам список предметов. Нужно узнать самый любимый предмет студентов (посчитать сколько раз встречается предмет и вывести предмет который встретился больше раз)

```
subject_list = ["Biology","Math","Geography ","Physics","English"]

students_list = [ ["Mike", "English"], ["Leana", "Biology"], ["Oleg", "Math"],  ["Ivan", "Biology"], ["Mikola", "Math"], ["Hanna", "Biology"], ["Lena", "Geography"], ["Nick", "Physics"]  ]
```

Comment: `[ [ pred, [p for n, p in  students_list].count(pred) ] for pred in subject_list ]`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте класс `Counter`, который подсчитает частоту элементов списка:

```
from collections import Counter

favorite_subject_list = [element[1] for element in students_list] 
favorite_subject = Counter(favorite_subject_list).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
In[1]: [element[1] for element in students_list]
```

Читайте это выражение (так называемое *«генератор списка»*) справа влево:

«Для всякого элемента `element` из списка `students_list` выбери `element[1]`, т.е. второй член пары.»

(Элементами вашего списка являются *пары,* например первым элементом пара `["Mike", "English"]`.)

Таким образом вы получите

> ```
> ['English',
>  'Biology',
>  'Math',
>  'Biology',
>  'Math',
>  'Biology',
>  'Geography',
>  'Physics']
> ```

Теперь будем постепенно конструировать выражение во второй команде, добавляя в каждом шаге *что-то за конец предыдущего:*

```
In[2]: Counter(favorite_subject_list)
```

> ```
> Counter({'English': 1, 'Biology': 3, 'Math': 2, 'Geography': 1, 'Physics': 1})
> ```

Мы получили объект типа `Counter`, который сохраняет элементы вашего списка *вместе с их частотами.*

Теперь применим метод `.most_common()`, который выберет из этого объекта определенное количество пар *со самыми большими числами частот.* Мы хотим только *одну* пару (т.е. пару со *самой большой частотой*), потому как параметр задаем число `1`:

```
In[3]: Counter(favorite_subject_list).most_common(1)
```

> ```
> [('Biology', 3)]
> ```

Это *список* (хотя только с одним элементом — кортежей) - выберем его первый (единый) элемент, т.е. элемент с индексом `0`:

```
In[4]: Counter(favorite_subject_list).most_common(1)[0]
```

> ```
> ('Biology', 3)
> ```

и с полученной кортежи опять элемент с индексом `0`:

```
In[5]: Counter(favorite_subject_list).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

> ```
> 'Biology'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

frequencies = defaultdict(int)
for __, subject in students_list:
    frequencies[subject] += 1

max_frequency = max(frequencies.values())

for subject in frequencies:
    if frequencies[subject] == max_frequency:
        print(subject)
        break
```

Этот код выводит *только один* самый любимый предмет. Когда вы хотите вывести *все* самые любимые предметы (т.к. может быть *несколько* таких), уберите команду `break`.

Преимущество `defaultdict()` в том, что не надо тестировать, если ключ в словаре уже существует — когда не существует, полагается, что его значением есть *стандартное значение* (default). Для `defaultdict(int)` стандартным значением нуль (0).

---

Добавление: Без `defaultdict` — некрасиво, но когда вы так хотите...

```
frequencies = {}                     # Пустой словарь
for __, subject in students_list:
    if subject in frequencies:
        frequencies[subject] += 1
    else:
        frequencies[subject] = 0

max_frequency = max(frequencies.values())

for subject in frequencies:
    if frequencies[subject] == max_frequency:
        print(subject)
        break
```

(Разница только в первой части, до `max_frequency = ...` )

Comment: Можно как то без def?

Comment: Можно, я добавил код к моему ответу. Но рекомендую привыкать к такому стилю, это нет Питонический подход.